# 2 printers under devices

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I added my new hp wifi printer, but under devices it appears as two printers. They have just slightly different names and also the icons are different.

Both seem to work though.

Names:
HP-Color-LaserJet-MFP-M477fdw,driverless
HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M477fdw_DB23CE_

the later one seems to disappear when in sleep mode.

is this a standard configuration?

can anyone explain why? i find it rather confusing.

ps: fax has been turned off, so this doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: trying to "solve" this minor issue brought me in a lot of problems so for now i think i should leave this as it is once i solved my other problems. but is till find it really strange